# stop json stream

Tags: php, twitter, curl

I found this code 
(full version here http://blog.loicg.net/developpement-web/lire-twitter-stream-php-curl)

```
function read_the_stream($sTrackingList){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json');
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,TWITTER_LOGIN.':'.TWITTER_PASSWORD);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Twitter-Client: ItsMe','X-Twitter-Client-Version: 0.1','X-Twitter-Client-URL: http://rien.net/'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"track=".$sTrackingList);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_callback');

 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
}
```

It's work for me but now i don't know how to stop it (for making test it's horrible, my new php file not interpreted!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either put this code inside a script that is not executed on a webpage (like a daemon) or you should not use the stream.

If you want to get only 100 tweets, then use some of the other twitter API for that.

If you want a stop button, consider:

- have your other script populate some database (or a queue like redis or ActiveMQ) and then you can have your webpage get your own stream using AJAX
- Simply using AJAX to call a script that reads the feeds.

Comment: I can make a daemon on a mutual server. I want to detect when a new tweet arrives so the stream is the only one solution or make 350 detectiond per hour (not fun).
Any solution to say at twitter, stop running this request ?

Comment: Well.... you can run the stream in a fork but that is not easy.  If you fork, you can close the work whenever you want which will close the stream automatically.  The other solution which seems better is to have one command line script (daemon) wich will query the twitter stream non-stop and populate some data storage and you use AJAX to query your own data storage every 5 seconds.  Why do you want to STOP the request excacly?